# How do I specify the allowable IP addresses to my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to restrict the allowable IP addresses that can access my Azure App/Web Service. I've seen it done once before. I remember the demo showing how you can have Azure determine the IP address you're accessing Azure from, so it can come up with the range of IP addresses. But I don't have notes on how that presenter did it. I've tried searching for it and came across this [Azure App Service Static IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions). But unless I'm mistaken, that method of restricting IP addresses doesn't use my current IP address to determine a range. So, I'm thinking there must be another way. Am I correct about this or is the description in the link I gave the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Web Apps doesn't provide the ability to automatically add a rule for your current IP address, but there are lots of web sites you can visit, designed to report your current external IP address to you, which you can then add to the IP list. FYI the Azure SQL Database Service *does* let you add your current IP address to its firewall - that's likely where you saw it.

In case you were asking where to configure IP address restrictions: That's located in the `Networking` tab.

[image: Networking tab: IP restrictions]

Comment: Yes! It was the Azure SQL Database Service that I was thinking about! Thank you!! And moreover, thank you for the graphic on configuring the IP addresses restrictions as well.